# Discord Bot Delete Messages in Specific Channel

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

TIA for your help and apologies, I'm a newbie so this may be a foolish question. I've searched through and can't find anything specific on how to make a discord bot (in Python) delete messages only within a specific channel. I want all messages sent to a specific channel to be deleted, their contents sent via PM to the user and the user's role changed.

Is there a way to use on_message and specify in an specific channel?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
user = message.author
if message.content.startswith("Cluebot:"):
    await message.delete()
    await user.send("Yes?")
    await user.remove_roles(get(user.guild.roles, "Investigator"))
```

The problem I'm having is I'm also using commands which now no longer work because the bot only responds if the message begins with "Cluebot:" Can I have the bot only look for "Cluebot:" in a specific channel?

Is it possible to make this work through a command instead of an event?

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Apologies! I've found a workaround: 

@client.command()
async def reveal(ctx, *, answer):
    user=ctx.message.author
    if answer == solution:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await user.send("You're a winner!")
        await user.remove_roles(get(user.guild.roles, "Investigator"))
    else:
        await user.remove_roles(get(user.guild.roles, "Investigator"))
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await user.send("Sorry, " + answer + "is not the correct answer.")

Answer (score 1):

*The problem I'm having is I'm also using commands which now no longer work because the bot only responds if the message begins with "Cluebot:" Can I have the bot only look for "Cluebot:" in a specific channel?*

About this problem the clue is:

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

as docs says [*Without this coroutine, none of the commands will be triggered.*](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20process#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)

about the main question you could try using `get_channel` by ID and then purge it:
eg.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    purgeChannel = client.get_channel([CHANNEL ID]])
     await purgeChannel.purge(limit=1)
```

you can add `check` to `purge()` to check for deleting specific message:
eg.:

```
def check(message):
    return message.author.id == [author's ID]

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    purgeChannel = client.get_channel([CHANNEL ID]])
     await purgeChannel.purge(limit=1, check=check)
```